# SharePoint 2010 Blog site template and post security

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I asked this question on msdn forums but got no response in 24 hours. I am pasting the question here, I am sure you guys out there can help me :)

This is my first post:

I created a blog site with SP 2010. Anonymous access is enabled. Home page is accessible by all users but when the user clicks on a post title, security window pops up and asks for credentials. In short, post details are not visible to anonymous users. Anyone knows why?

And this is my answer to myself:

Ok, I turned off lock down mode and disabling access to _layouts and other special folders with web.config but I don't feel like this is the right way to handle the issue. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/12/22/blog-site-in-anonymous-use/ not to deactivate viewformpageslockdown at site collection level but to do the same only to Blog sites (subsites).

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on both the posts & comments lists - make sure that anonymous access is turned on there.

Comment: Anonymous access is enabled for the entire site. Both Posts list and the post items in the list are inheriting permission from site and anonymous users have View Items permission on both.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around, I found the solution and have successfully implemented it :-)

Publishing sites have the Viewformpageslockdown feature enabled (it's an additional security layer). Disable it, and you're good to go!

Sylvie, not sure if your mention of "turned off lock down mode" is this? It worked for me.

More info here:
http://www.petestilgoe.com/tag/viewformpageslockdown/

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/12/22/blog-site-in-anonymous-use/ not to deactivate viewformpageslockdown at site collection level but to do similar permission granting only to Blog sites (subsites) to get Blog entries working with viewformpageslockdown feature activated at site collection level.